# jQuery tabs keep loading when tab loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am trying to create an ajax-loading jQuery tab, as per the example at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

However I noticed that, after the ajax loading starts, if I change the selected tab, the XHR request is aborted and restarted again when I then re-select the ajax tab.

How can I keep the tab loading even if the user changes the current tab? As of now, I have only been able to prevent it reloading each time with the following option:

```
beforeLoad: function(e, ui) {
    if(ui.panel.data('loaded') || ui.panel.data('loading')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    ui.panel.data('loading', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        block_element(ui.panel.css('min-height', 175), I18N('FULLCALENDAR_LOADING'));
    }, 500);

    ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
        ui.panel.data('loading', false);
        ui.panel.data('loaded', true);
    });
    ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
        ui.panel.data('loading', false);
        ui.panel.data('loaded', false);
    });

    // se era specificata una funzione
    if(typeof old === 'function') {
        // la chiamo
        old.call(this, e, ui);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your whole code by creating a jsfiddle?